# Should I learn how web frameworks work before I use them?

Tags: frameworks

I'm interested in creating a basic web application (for learning, but I want to finish within a few months), and I've read that using a web framework can make that task much easier.

After reading about different frameworks online, it seems to me that using frameworks would hide a lot of detail on they work. I fear that if I use a framework, I won't really know how my website is running.

Is it important to understand how frameworks do what they do, or am I worrying too much? (eg. I don't know how the Linux kernel works, or the C compiler, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** (to some extent) important to understand how frameworks work, but you'll never learn that without using them.
So, start using some framework and you'll get basic understanding of it. And then, if you have interest, you can always dig deeper into it (maybe even submit patches and participate in its development). But not in the opposite order.

Using your analogy, you don't become Linux kernel developer without being Linux user for some time.

Comment: Thanks, your analogy made a lot of sense and put me at ease. I don't have enough reputation to upvote :(

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't have a particular interest in web frameworks, I would say it's good to play with a few and then crack them open if only for the exposure to new design patterns and solutions that can be applied anywhere in development. (MVC in particular when talking about most web frameworks)